# Not able to display images in Jekyll's posts

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

In my Jekyll blog I have a collection called _documents where I publish posts that are more important than the usual. I am able to publish images in these posts with the code `![](./../assets/images/test.png)` since I am using markdown. Since the publication date of this post is not important the name of the files do not start with a date.

Then I have the standard posts in the folder _posts. When I try to publish an image in those the URL gets changed by adding the year and the month before. For example, what should be `https://name.github.io/blog/assets/images/test.png` is `https://name.github.io/blog/2020/04/assets/images/test.png` and the image does not load.

How can I make sure that Jekyll does not use the date when referencing images?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the markdown to:

```
![](/assets/images/test.png)
```

If that doesn't work, see if there are any errors in the console (F12), like a 404 Not Found error on the image.

Comment: It more or less works. I have to write:
    ![](/blog/assets/images/test.png)

Comment: Yes, it all depends on how you've set your permalink in your `_config.yml`. I usually have it set as `permalink: "/blog/:title/"`. Adjust accordingly to your setup.